# iOS layout woes - on 4s, the bottom button is unhittable

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm making an app that supports 4s through to iPad (portrait only).
One view controller is set out roughly like this with these constraints:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tNlJ.png

The third button at the bottom when I launch on iPhone 4s can't be tapped. 
Anyone have any idea why this might be?

Comment: Are these views inside a ```UIScrollView```?

Comment: Also, try enabling ```clip subviews``` on your bottom view to make sure that your third button is not out of bounds.

Comment: No scrollview and clib suviews is not ticked

Comment: Try ticking it, and tell me what you see. Does the third button get cut out?

Comment: Yes it does get cut out. Does that mean the view isn't big enough?

Comment: Yes, check my answer for a potential fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is the bottom constraint of 128 pt on your bottom view. You should let your buttons drive the size of your bottom view. To do this, remove all constraints on the bottom view except for the align center to superview one.

Then, have your first and third buttons be tied to their superview through a top and bottom constraint respectively.

Also, have your first button be tied to it's superview with a leading and trailing constraints.

Finally, make sure all buttons have width and height constraints. And also, the second button should be tied to your first and last buttons, through top and bottom constraints, of course.

Comment: If I take away the 128 constraint the view with the buttons rises to cover the top view with the labels. I don't know how to set the space between those two views. When I control click from one to the other there's no contraint that comes up for that.

Comment: Are those two constraints siblings? Make sure they are at the same level, inside a single super view. As an alternative try using the Xcode controls in the bottom right corner of the Interface File.

Comment: Yep using the xcode controls made it easier. Still very confused by this autolayout stuff though. Thanks for the help

Comment: There's definitely a learning curve involved but I think it's worth exploring. Try to look for the simplest solution when laying out your views. Think outside the box. :)